# Using Electro-galvanic_oxygen_sensor ; Oxygen concentration varying b/w 19% to 30% for ambient air (which should be 21%)

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor

We are using Oxygen sensor from SGX Sensortech. The datasheet link is attached here. [[link]](https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2020/04/DS-0340-SGX-VOX-datasheet-1.pdf).
We are using ARM Cortex-M7 core. The ADC voltage range is 0-3.3V, it has 12 bit ADC. 
We are using OPA388 (Zero-Drift, Zero-Crossover,) operational amplifier from Texas Instruments in the non-inverting configuration. We have selected the gain of 40. The circuit is shown below.

The sensor gives output of 9-13mV for 21% O2 concentration, which translates to ca. 45mV - 65mV at 100% O2.

**Experimental value:**

Voltage from the sensor 10.2 mV. After amplification from Opamp we are getting 0.405 (405 mV). The gain of the amplifier is set at 40. 
*In the program we are getting variation in the oxygen concentration from 19% to 30% (it should be 21%).* 
We are using a shielded cable pair and our wire length is one meter from sensor to the controller.

The logic of the program is:
First it will measure the mV at 21% stores the value ; the voltage from O2 sensor vary linearly from 21% to 100% of O2 concentration.

We are planning to moving avg filter or Kalman filter to reduce variations. 
Any recommendations, mistakes in the above logic/ circuit.

[image]

Comment: Try sampling at mains frequency to see if that gives a stable reading by eliminating variations in mains pickup. Report back in your question and we'll go from there.

Comment: What happens if you use a nice bench power supply to provide 0.4V to the ADC? Do you get steady readings or large variation?

Comment: The opa388 output swing could be upwards of 15mv from ground.

Comment: How are you temperature compensating the membrane? Also, is the voltage the mcu sees tracking what it really is, like compared to multitester?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C12 is really bad ju-ju. You must not put much of a capacitor directly on the output of most op-amps or they will oscillate. It would be better to have the RC filter at the input of the op-amp anyway, you could use 10K + 100nF, for example.

A few hundred pF is okay with [this op-amp](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2388.pdf?ts=1591730565056) at G=1 (worst-case) but 100,000pF is not okay. The Zener and the ADC input will have some capacitance, but that's okay. From the datasheet:

[image]

As generally good practice, you might want to add a 1M to ground at the input so the reading goes to approximately zero rather than drifting around if the sensor happens to get disconnected.

Comment: [OPA388 Figure 26, Page 15.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa388.pdf?ts=1591730794255&ref_url=https://www.ti.com/product/OPA388) In case anyone wonders where the chart came from.

Comment: Removed 0.1uF cap (C12) & Zener diode (ZD4), then it is showing stable readings, 20.5% O2 concentration in ambient air.

Comment: @TapasX Thank you for the feedback, it is always good to know when the suggested solution does the trick.