# Translating 9 - 13mV to \$\mathrm{O_2}\$ level

Tags: sensor

Output of O<sub>2</sub> sensor varies between 9 - 13 mV. For example for this sensor [link](https://www.kempstoncontrols.co.uk/AA829-M20/Other/sku/963633).

First I thought it 9 mV for %0 and 13 mV for %100 level. After reading this [link2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504613/using-electro-galvanic-oxygen-sensor-oxygen-concentration-varying-b-w-19-to-3), I understood that I was thinking wrong.

How can I read O<sub>2</sub> level from analog voltage? Do I need multiplying by 5 for %100 level? (e.g., 9 x 5 - 13 x 5 => 45 - 65 mV.) That is correct?

Comment: It looks like this sensor has an accuracy of about 1% and the output can change by 5% per year due to aging. In one comment you said you want 0.1% resolution, so be prepared to recalibrate often.

Answer (score 2):

Gain = 5 for 0 to 100% range = 9 to 45mV (min offset).
Offset = 9 to 14 mV.

- first you adjust for offset error using 100% N2
- second you adjust using 100% O2 for calibration as defined in sensor manual
- Using a 4 point linear curve fit may reduce gain error <1%

Load : 10 kohm min.

You can choose any gain and max out range you want.  What do you prefer?
How do you intend to calibrate? s/w or h/w?

Comment: O2 range that must measured is between 0-25% with 0.1% resolution. Also i need to generate an alarm when below the 18% and 19%. Your first 3 sentences looks complex to understand?

Comment: I prefer calibration via S/W.

Comment: I tried to reword. This is like any ADC offset and gain Calibration

Comment: Reworded  again...  finger typing and bad iOS auto spellcorrecter ;)

Comment: Does 100% N2 means 0% O2 ?

Comment: Yes it does... redundant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123785/discussion-between-berker-isik-and-tony-stewart-ee75).